# Is this efficient looping JavaScript coding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Is this for loop code written efficiently?**

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

There are actually several ways! to writing this code with efficiently

Comment: You should accumulate the new elements in an array, or add them to a dom fragment, and then append them after the loop.  In general, if you are focusing on efficiency, you want to touch the DOM as little as possible.

Comment: sure, but a real-world something wouldn't ever be written/made like that (using: document.body.appendChild).

Comment: efficient is not really the appropriate term...

Comment: Yes, the JavaScript bit is fine, as mentioned your DOM bit not so.

Comment: Might want to check out what Jason Miller (of preact fame) says about [textContent vs text nodes](https://youtu.be/LY6y3HbDVmg?t=1115). Hint: text nodes are about twice as fast.

Comment: There's not really an alternative to this loop when the objective is to create 200 elements. Not sure what kind of "efficiency" you are asking about.

Comment: Your question is too generic, what do you mean by efficiently? Speed performance or maintainability wise?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Interacting with the dom is usually the most expensive operation, much more than anything you'll do within the JavaScript code. Let's say for example you can do calculations with an array of one million in length, but you'll hardly be able to impact the dom one million times smoothly.</s>

<s>As for the example, would be a lot more efficient to call appendChild only once, like so:</s>

Apparently I was wrong. Calling createElement in the same redrawing seems to be as expensive as doing it only once, even less so. Here is the test, and I will improve the question after some research:

```js
let start, end

// Call appendChild for every paragraph

start = new Date().getTime()

for (let i = 1; i <= 30000; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;
    document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}

end = new Date().getTime()
console.log('Execution time: ' + (end - start))

// Call appendChild only once, with a div containing all paragraphs

start = new Date().getTime()

let insertHtml = ""
for (let i = 1; i <= 30000; i++) {
  insertHtml += `<p>This is paragraph number ${i}</p>`
}
const newElement = document.createElement('div')
newElement.innerHTML = insertHtml

document.body.appendChild(newElement)

end = new Date().getTime()
console.log('Execution time: ' + (end - start))
```

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. If you call `createElement` a bunch but nothing triggers the browser to paint, it will batch up the changes into a single repaint.